# Работа со звуком в C# - непрерывное считывание в буфер уровней 2-канального звукового сигнала

Tags: c#

Какими инструментами лучше воспользоваться для непрерывного считывания в буфер уровней 2-канального звукового сигнала с микрофонного или линейного входа звуковой карты, с параллельным отображением этих уровней на индикаторах?

Данные из буфера, после отображения и измерения пикового уровня, становятся не актуальны, т.е. нигде не сохраняются.

Comment: Считывание с микрофонного или линейного входа звуковой карты.

Comment: Почитай про библиотеку NAudio http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Это читал и читаю. Нужен совет от программистов, имеющих опыт работы со звуком, какие функции и процедуры они посоветовали бы для каждого из этапов - захват, отображение, выборочное чтение из буфера.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы и желание помочь!